# How to access the current model from the controller in C# MVC 5?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model, controller

I am new to C# MVC and I have a big form to build. The form is to create/edit an instance of my main model (AcModel) and it is spanning on several tabs (all of them being in the same view). It contains several Telerik grids that are filled using different models (each one representing a table in the database).

So when the user clicks on the button to get to the next tab I want to trigger validation for the piece of form he just entered. In one of the grids the user can add, update or remove data from another model. So when he clicks on the button to submit a line in the grid, an action from my controller is called with that model as an argument. But I don't want to call the service to update the db at this point because I first need the id of my main object being created by the form.

For those grids whose selected values can't be bound directly to a field from my main model, I want to update the model if it passes validation as the user goes to the next tab, and only when he reaches the end of the form and submits it do I want to call the service and update the db for every field in my form.

So here it is: how can I access my main model from its controller ? I could serialize it to Json from the view and pass it to the controller via the ViewBag and return it from my action but the returned view does not contain the inputs from the user and that's dirty and there must be a simpler/cleaner way.

Here is my grid in the view (Views/Ac/_ACForm.cshtml):

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Erakis.Domain.PerimetreProduit.Models.ListeAcPprModel>()
  .Name("grid-ac-ppr")
  .DataSource(ds => ds
      .Ajax()
      .Model(m => m.Id(p => p.LacID))
      .PageSize(10)
      .Events(e => e.Error("error_handler"))
      .Create(update => update.Action("AcPpr_Create", "Ac"))
      .Read(read => read.Action("AcPpr_Read", "Ac", new { IdAC = Model.AcID }))
      .Update(update => update.Action("AcPpr_Update", "Ac"))
      .Destroy(update => update.Action("AcPpr_Destroy", "Ac")))
  .Columns(c =>
  {
      c.ForeignKey(p => p.PprID, (List<ListePprModel>)ViewBag.PPRs, "Ppr_Id", "Ppr_Libelle");
      c.Bound(p => p.QteMin);
      c.Bound(p => p.CAMin);
      c.Command(command => { command.Edit(); command.Destroy(); });
  })
  .ToolBar(t => t.Create())
  .Filterable()
  .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine)))
```

Here is the model used to fill my grid:

```
public class ListeAcPprModel
{
    public int LacID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> PprID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> AcoID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> QteMin { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> CAMin { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> IsExclusion { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> TypePerimetre { get; set; }
}
```

And (part of) my main model (AcModel):

```
public class AcModel
{
    (...)
    public virtual ICollection<ListeAcPprModel> AC_PPR_MODELs { get; set; }
}
```

Here is a typical action in my controller (Controllers/AcController.cs):

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> AcPpr_Update([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest Request, ListeAcPprModel AcPpr)
{
    if (AcPpr != null && ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // Here I want to update one of the items in the property AC_PPR_MODELs of AcModel, which is an ICollection, with the AcPpr that I got from the view
    }
    return Json(new[] { AcPpr }.ToDataSourceResult(Request, ModelState));
}
```

Thank you very much for your help!